# NiFi S2S communication issue - Site2SiteBulletinReportingTask - using NiFi 1.16.3

Tags: apache-nifi

I have an issue with the S2S and when i start the controller service i am getting the following wartning and nothing comes on the bulletingPort

SiteToSiteBulletinReportingTask[id=711849c0-0187-1000-ffff-ffff8be39fac] Unable to refresh remote group peers due to: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

The StandardRestrictedSSLContext and given the path everything is correct and i have used nls-toolkit to generate the certificate and i have 4 nodes running the niFi processors and thats the only difference. If you guys can help how to generate the certificate for all four nodes that can communicate easily then it will be great and i have used the following tutorial but still no luck

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/NIFI-S2S-communication-issue-between-two-secured-NIFI/td-p/193227

I have tried creating the certificate using keytools and as wells ns-toolkit but merging command keytools is not working and i dont get the certificate merged, If we have clear documentation how we can do it then it will be great